# i want to set array of images from drawable but dont know how to done this on kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

getting an error type mismatch from class
this is my coding ,

```
class quoteforlove : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quoteforlove)
        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagev)
        val btnn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonq)
        val random = Random()
        var imageIdList = arrayOf<Int>(
                R.drawable.aaa,
                R.drawable.download,
                R.drawable.hh,
                R.drawable.iii,
                R.drawable.ik,
                R.drawable.images)
        btnn.setOnClickListener(
                imageView.setImageResource(random.nextInt(imageIdList.count()))

        )
    }
```

i want that when the button is click image view get random image from drawable

Comment: this looks like a syntax error. if you use android studio you should get a hint

Answer (score 0):

it looks you try to set code that changes the image as the parameter and not as onClickListener defined as lambda. Correct definition should be:

```
btnn.setOnClickListener {
    imageView.setImageResource(random.nextInt(imageIdList.count()))
}
```

Comment: He needs to actually use a drawable from within the array, not just a random integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an actual drawable, not just a random int:

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageIdList[random.nextInt(imageIdList.count())])
```